# Plotting a blackbody radiation curve using matplotlib, but I dont understand the error I'm getting?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, physics

```
import math
import random
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

```
h=6.62607015E-34 # Planck constant, units of J*s
hbar=h/(2*math.pi) # Reduced Planck constant 
k=1.380649E-23 # Boltzmann constant, units of J/K
c=299792458.00 # speed of light M/s
sb=(2*(math.pi**5)*(k**4))/(15*(c**2)*(h**3)) # Stefan-Boltzmann constant, units of W/(m^2 K^4)
```

```
def one_star():
    mass=random.uniform(0.1,50) # random mass in relation to the sun's mass
    print("The mass of the star is "+str(mass)+" times the mass of the Sun")
    if mass <= 1.4: # given by the mass-radius relationship
        radius=mass**0.9
        print("The radius of the star is "+str(radius)+" times the radius of the Sun")
    else:
        radius=mass**0.6 # larger stars are less dense
        print("The radius of the star is "+str(radius)+" times the radius of the Sun")

    # To find the volume and surface area of the star, we want values in terms of meters^3 and meters^2
    # So we'll multiply each of the previous values by the Sun's mass and radius.
    mass_actual=mass*1.989E28 # mass in kilograms
    print("The mass of the star in kilograms: "+str(mass_actual))
    radius_actual=radius*696000000 # radius in meters
    print("The radius of the star in meters: "+str(radius_actual))   
    volume=(4/3)*math.pi*(radius_actual**3) # volume in meters cubed
    print("The volume of the star in meters cubed: "+str(volume))    
    sa=4*math.pi*(radius_actual**2) # surface area in meters squared
    print("The surface area of the star in meters squared: "+str(sa))    
    B=random.uniform(3.3,3.7)
    luminosity=mass**B # we are using the value of mass in relation to the sun's mass again for this part
    print("The luminosity of the star is "+str(luminosity)+" times the luminosity of the Sun")
    # Time to find the temperature
    # We need to convert the luminosity of the star into real units now
    l_actual=luminosity*3.828E26
    print("The luminosity of the star in watts: "+str(l_actual))
    temperature=(l_actual/(sa*sb))**(1/4) # Solved Stefan-Boltzmann law for temperature
                                          # sb is the Stefan-Boltzmann constant
    print("The surface temperature of the star in Kelvin: "+str(temperature))

    ####### Time to produce a blackbody radiation curve #######

    T=temperature
    x=np.arange(1,1000)
    Intensity=((2*h*c**2)/(x**5))(1/(exp(((h*c)/(x*k*T)-1))
    plt.plot(x, Intensity, '--', label='Intensity')
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')
    plt.title("Planck Blackbody Radiation Curve")
    plt.xlabel("Wavelength")
    plt.ylabel("Intensity")

    plt.show()
```

I am trying to plot a blackbody radaiation curve for a given star's temperature. The issue I am getting is [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzpEC.png). The code above the Plot functions is all correct and works, I have left it in for reference. I'm sure this is an easy fix, but I am unfamiliar with how to plot functions like this? All of my imports and defined variables are above the code.

Comment: Look at the line before. It ends with a `]`, which can't be right.

Comment: I went and fixed it, still same error. :/

Comment: That just means that there are still further errors on that line: too few `)`s, missing multiplication sign, etc. I suggest breaking that line into smaller pieces and assigning them to temporary variables so you can follow it more clearly.

Comment: The error I am getting doesn't have to do with the `Intensity=` line? my error is on line `plt.plot(x, Intensity, '--', label='intensity')`. I've already gone through the equation and fixed all errors. I can print it with actual values and get the proper output.

Comment: You haven't posted an error.

Comment: Your `Intensity` line has many errors: 1) no`*` between the `)` and `(` -- a common problem when translating math equations with its assumed multiplication for adjacent symbols; 2) your parens don't match; 3) `exp` is not defined; etc. All-in-all, this is not the way to go about coding -- writing a bunch of stuff that doesn't work and then posting your typos for StackOverflow to figure out. You need a new approach. People here are generally happy to help, but this wastes everybody's time and you won't really learn anything.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive feedback, I thought I had that line figured out since I was getting outputs elsewhere. I am still new to coding, and especially here on stack overflow. I'll keep your advice in mind the next time I ask for help on here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with

```py
Intensity=((2*h*c**2)/(x**5))(1/(exp(((h*c)/(x*k*T)-1))
```

The parentheses are unbalanced, there is a missing `*` between closed sets of parentheses, and the `exp` function is undefined. Since `x` is a `np.ndarray` you need to use `np.exp` instead of `math.exp`, so it should be

```py
Intensity = ((2 * h * c**2) / x**5) * (1 / (np.exp((h * c) / (x * k * T)) - 1))
```

However it should also be noted that the range `(1, 1000)` is fairly useless in this situation, since `x` (wavelength) is in *meters*, and the radiation between 1 m and 1 km wavelengths is not very interesting. It should be more like `(1e-8, 1e-6)` (10 nm to 1 um) which can be generated by `np.linspace(1e-8, 1e-6, 1000)` and would then give the normal blackbody curves:

[image]

---

#### Complete example code

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math

h = 6.62607015e-34
k = 1.380649e-23
c = 299792458.00
sb = (2 * math.pi**5 * k**4) / (15 * c**2 * h**3)

def one_star():
    mass = np.random.uniform(0.1, 50)
    radius = mass**0.9 * 6.96e8
    B = np.random.uniform(3.3, 3.7)
    sa = 4 * math.pi * radius**2
    T = (luminosity / (sa * sb))**(1/4)
    x = np.linspace(1e-8, 1e-6, 1000)
    I = ((2 * h * c**2) / x**5) * (1 / (np.exp((h * c) / (x * k * T)) - 1))
    plt.plot(x, I)

for i in range(5):
    one_star()
plt.show()
```